# Starlink App and Router

Tags: discussion

Are questions about the Starlink mobile app and router configuration on topic in Space Exploration (tagged Starlink)?

Comment: FYI, [Superuser appears to have questions and answers about Starlink](https://superuser.com/search?q=starlink).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  Questions about internet configuration are not among the topics in the [Help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  The internet coming from space does not make it more relevant here.

There ARE on-topic questions about the Starlink satellite constellation and how it communicates with ground stations, but questions about the details of its usage by an end-user should be asked elsewhere.